# Automatically changing the docker container file permissions in a directory in Linux

Tags: linux, docker, permissions, containers, docker-volume

We have a docker container running in Linux VMs. This container is writing the logs inside a directory in the container.

Container log directory - /opt/log/

This directory in volume mounted to host machine so that all the log files will also be available in host.

Host directory - /var/log/

Here we see container is creating the log files with 600 (-rw-------+) permission. There is no group read permission assigned to these files.

Same permissions are reflecting in host directory also. We need to add group read permission (640) (-rw-r-----+) automatically for all the files getting created in this directory so that other logging agents can read these files.

I have tried setting ACL also for adding this permission on host but these permissions are not getting set for the files inside this directory.

```
setfacl -Rdm g::r-- /var/log/
```

Is there a way we can add group read permission automatically for all the files getting created in this host directory?

Comment: we had a similar issue, we couldn't enable acl and the umask was simply ignored by the process generating files. In the end we opted to use the same UID in the containers reading and writing those files.

Answer (score 1):

From the following article,

https://dille.name/blog/2018/07/16/handling-file-permissions-when-writing-to-volumes-from-docker-containers/

There is a parameter to set the user id and the group id for example, 
`docker run -it --rm --volume $(pwd):/source --workdir /source --user $(id -u):$(id -g) ubuntu`

To set the permissions of the user, when starting the container.

Comment: We have a user present in container which is not in host machine and container has to start with this user only. I tried passing these parameters but it did not worked.

Comment: id -u without specifying a user, is the user currently logged into the host machine, or the current user. so you do not have this user on your host machine, so you can change the parameters for -u and -g parameter to the one you require, which is on the container. I have included information on the id command https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/id.1.html